# Mi componente VueJS no es capaz de leer mis props en el template. (Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'titulo' of undefined")

Tags: vue.js, component

tengo mi componente vuejs que recibe en props un objeto que puede venir vacio o no, en el caso de que venga vacio le tengo puesto valores por defecto para el v-model funcione, en teoria siempre. Lo que pasa que el template de dicho componente no lee el objeto que le paso por props.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <form action="propuesta/store" method="post">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <label>Tipo de propuesta:
                            <i id="icono" class=""></i>
                        </label>
                        <select id="select_tipo_propuesta" class="form-control w-50" name="tipo_propuesta_id" required>
                            <option value="">-- Seleccionar --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 ">
                        <i id="icono" class="mt-5"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Titulo:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo de la propuesta" required v-model="propuesta.titulo">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Descripción:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="descripcion" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Explica los mas detalladamente posible lo que pretendes hacer, que que necesitas y cuanto crees que podrias tardar." required v-model="propuesta.descripcion" ></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:{
            propuesta:{
                titulo:{default:'',type:String},
                descripcion:{default:'',type:String}
            }
        },
        data(){
            return{
            }
        },

        beforeMount(){
            // this.preSet();
        },
        mounted() {
        },
        methods:{
            //Funcion para cargar todo lo necesario para el CRUD
            // preSet(){
            // }
        },
        computed: {
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la solución, la dejo aqui por si alguien tropieza con el mismo problema :

```
 props:{
            propuesta: {
                type: Object,
                default () {
                    return {
                        titulo: '',
                        descripcion: ''
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Te la estaba comentando jajaja, te vas a encontrar un problema con tu implementacion y es que estas usando un v-model con un prop, a la hora de editarlo te va a dar warning/error porque no se supone que puedas editar valores de hijos a padres de esa manera. Tendras que crear un data que se asocie al valor del prop y un watch para cuando cambie el prop actualizar el data, o usar el sync modifier. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier

Comment: @larizzatg jajaja gracias igualmente, pues lo que yo hacia antes era poner al props : param_(nombre_variable) y en el data ponia: (variable) = this.$props.(nombre_variable), porque me daba errores al llamar el prop y el data igual (algo que no entiendo porque si estan en dos contextos diferentes y para llamarlos se hace llamando a un contexto diferente, me imagino que sera por el template)